# NoMethodError for nil object on sort_by, and all objects exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, sorting, null

So I have a bunch of users, who all have user.dj_name attributes.  It's a validated necessity on the model, but I'm still being cautious here because I'm running into problems.

I want to get a bunch of users, then order them by their dj_name.  Something like this:

```
@djs = Event.all.map { |e| e.program.user }.sort_by {|x,y| x.dj_name <=> y.dj_name }
```

where it's pulling all DJs who have Events (shows).  It fails with "NoMethodError: undefined method `dj_name' for nil:NilClass"

So I tried:

```
@djs = Event.all.map { |e| e.program.user }
@djs.compact.sort_by! {|x,y| x.dj_name <=> y.dj_name rescue nil}
```

And it doesn't sort.  Without the "rescue nil" clause, I get the same error.

And if I do a reject! if the object is nil I get nothing.

```
> @djs.reject! {|d| d.nil? }
=> nil
```

It seems like none of the objects in the array are nil, the sorting mechanism is giving me errors, and rescuing it just stops the sorting process and returns an unchanged array.

halp?

Comment: You shouldn't use an in line `rescue` and `compact` removes nil elements anyways.

Comment: Your error `NoMethodError for nil object` is telling you that the object that you are attempting to sort by is empty therefore when this being executed this error is being thrown.

Comment: This had me going crazy. I didn't scroll down to see the last answer, which was correct and which is what I was doing as well. I think you should accept that instead as it actually solves the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the database sort for this kind of task. You can resume your queries by using:

```
Event.all(:include => {:program => :user}, :order => 'users.dj_name')
```

Decoupling this query would result in the `include` method making the join associations on your models and the `order` creating an `ORDER BY` on your query.

Answer (score 3):

Use `sort!`, not `sort_by!`.

`sort_by!` passes a single argument into its block. So, when you call `.sort_by! {|x,y| ... }`, `y` is always `nil`.

The purpose of `sort_by!` is to sort by keys instead of elements. The block gets a single element and must return the element's key to use for sorting.

In this code:

```
@djs.compact.sort_by! {|x,y| x.dj_name <=> y.dj_name rescue nil}
```

the block returns `nil` as a key for **every** element. As result, no sorting happens.

BTW, I agree with @MurifoX that in this particular case you should you database-provided sorting.